# How can I select a tag by xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have this html code

```
<td ng-repeat="month in fourMonth track by month.month" ng-class="month.class" ng-bind="month.label" ng-click="yearView.setMonth(month)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Feb</td>
```

to which I am trying to select in selenium by using xpath code

```
String monthReq = "Feb";
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[ng-bind='month.label' and contains(text(),'"+monthReq+"')]"));
```

but it gives no such element exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:Unable to locate element: //td[ng-bind='month.label' and contains(text(),'Feb')]
```

Comment: Check if the element is inside `<iframe>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think there is mistake in your XPath. 
Try This -

```
//td[@ng-bind='month.label' and contains(text(),'"+monthReq+"')]
```

or

```
//td[contains[text(),'"+monthReq+"']]
```